# not able to connect to Database ( Postgresql in my case ) in loopback4

Tags: node.js, postgresql, loopback4

As soon I make an app from loopback 4 cli , while running commad `npm run migrate` after `npm run build` I am getting an error

```
Migrating schemas (alter existing schema)
Cannot migrate database schema Error: Timeout in connecting after 5000 ms
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/manthan/Desktop/temp/temp/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:2654:10)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! temp@1.0.0 migrate: `node ./dist/migrate`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the temp@1.0.0 migrate script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/manthan/.npm/_logs/2020-05-22T06_41_17_958Z-debug.log
```

Datasource config is correct and if i run same code on other system it runs pretty well as desired .

Package.json as follows

```
{
  "name": "temp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "temp",
  "keywords": [
    "loopback-application",
    "loopback"
  ],
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "lb-tsc",
    "build:watch": "lb-tsc --watch",
    "lint": "npm run prettier:check && npm run eslint",
    "lint:fix": "npm run eslint:fix && npm run prettier:fix",
    "prettier:cli": "lb-prettier \"**/*.ts\" \"**/*.js\"",
    "prettier:check": "npm run prettier:cli -- -l",
    "prettier:fix": "npm run prettier:cli -- --write",
    "eslint": "lb-eslint --report-unused-disable-directives .",
    "eslint:fix": "npm run eslint -- --fix",
    "pretest": "npm run clean && npm run build",
    "test": "lb-mocha --allow-console-logs \"dist/__tests__\"",
    "posttest": "npm run lint",
    "test:dev": "lb-mocha --allow-console-logs dist/__tests__/**/*.js && npm run posttest",
    "docker:build": "docker build -t temp .",
    "docker:run": "docker run -p 3000:3000 -d temp",
    "migrate": "node ./dist/migrate",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "node -r source-map-support/register .",
    "clean": "lb-clean dist *.tsbuildinfo .eslintcache"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "files": [
    "README.md",
    "dist",
    "src",
    "!*/__tests__"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@loopback/boot": "^2.3.1",
    "@loopback/context": "^3.8.1",
    "@loopback/core": "^2.7.0",
    "@loopback/openapi-v3": "^3.4.1",
    "@loopback/repository": "^2.5.1",
    "@loopback/rest": "^5.0.1",
    "@loopback/rest-explorer": "^2.2.2",
    "@loopback/service-proxy": "^2.3.0",
    "loopback-connector-postgresql": "^3.9.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@loopback/build": "^5.4.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.19",
    "@loopback/testlab": "^3.1.5",
    "@types/node": "^10.17.24",
    "@loopback/eslint-config": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, I was able to solve by updating loopback-connector-postgresql dependence. In **package.json**  `"loopback-connector-postgresql": "^3.9.1"` was used, when I updated it to   `"loopback-connector-postgresql": "^5.4.0"` using Node version **14.17.0,** it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Timeout in connecting after 5000 ms
```

This means you are not able to connect to your datasource. Check your host address,  also check the permission of the user to access the database like(%@%).

Comment: I have checked user privileges and the host address is also correct ,  but the issue prevails , same error persists

Comment: In your datasource replace host IP with localhost

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently and my problem was, on separate occasions, one of the following (in no particular order):

- Database wasn't running
- If DB was running

  - It was on the wrong IP and/or port (Mine was localhost:5432)
  - The DB creds were different on each system
  - The database name is different on each system

I would first ensure the DB is running through another tool (gui/terminal). I don't know what type of datasource you're using but if it's postgres use [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/) (it's free). If it's MySQL use [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/). Once you know that the DB is actually running be sure to check that the credentials are not different.

So, you say `"on other system it runs pretty well as desired"`, this tells me that you have some DB running on that system (A) with the correct credentials. If running this project on the other system (B) doesn't work you might not have a DB running there. If it is running you may not have access to the DB b/c it's the wrong port or wrong credentials

All of the above are just assumptions based on limited information. Having a `servicefinder.datasource.ts` file to look at (sanitized for security of course) would help diagnose the issue better if not the nature of the two systems from above.

let me know if this helps.